# A reusable component that emits a value for the first subscriber when used multiple times

Tags: angular, components, subscription, reusability

I have created a reusable Angular component as shown below.

```
export enum ESwitchType {
    switch = 'switch',
    radio = 'radio',
    checkbox = 'checkbox',
}

export type TValidSize = 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl';

@Component({
    selector: 'jam-toggle',
    template: `
        <div
          [ngClass]="sizeClass"
          class="custom-control custom-switch"
        >
          <input
            (change)="changeValue($event)"
            [checked]="checked"
            type="checkbox"
            class="custom-control-input"
            id="customSwitch1"
          >
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1"></label>
        </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./toggle.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ToggleComponent extends BaseDetachedComponent implements OnInit {
    public checked: boolean = false;
    public switchType = ESwitchType;

    @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    @Input() type: ESwitchType;
    @Input() size: TValidSize = 'md';
    @Input() isDisabled = false;

    @Input() set value(value: boolean) {
        this.checked = value;
        this.detectChanges();
    }

    get sizeClass(): string {
        let classSize = '';
        switch (this.type) {
            case ESwitchType.switch:
                classSize = 'custom-switch-';
                break;
            case ESwitchType.checkbox:
                classSize = 'checkbox-';
                break;
            case ESwitchType.radio:
                classSize = 'custom-radio-';
                break;
        }

        return classSize + this.size;
    }

    constructor(
        protected cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ) {
        super(cdr);

        cdr.detach();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.detectChanges();
    }

    changeValue(event: Event): void {
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.valueChange.emit((event.target as HTMLInputElement).checked);

        this.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

html - reusable component.

Both "jam-toggle" components must fire events for different functions.

```
<jam-toggle
   class="ml-md-4"
   [type]="switchType.switch"
   [size]="'lg'"
   [value]="isHighlightsAutomaticGenerated"
   (valueChange)="automaticGeneratedHighlights($event)"
></jam-toggle>


<jam-toggle
   class="ml-md-4"
   [type]="switchType.switch"
   [size]="'md'"
   [value]="isPasswordStepVisible"
   (valueChange)="togglePasswordStep($event)"
></jam-toggle>
```

But the (valueChange) parameter only fires an event for the first subscriber

[visual example of behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlOVp.gif)

How can I listen for changes individually. For each component separately?

What did I miss?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

### The solution to the problem was to assign a unique ID to the elements.

detail:
[library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) was used for uniqueness

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';  // <<=== add Universally Unique Identifier

export enum ESwitchType {
    switch = 'switch',
    radio = 'radio',
    checkbox = 'checkbox',
}

export type TValidSize = 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl';

@Component({
    selector: 'jam-toggle',
    template: `
        <div
            [ngClass]="sizeClass"
            class="custom-control custom-switch"
        >
            <input
                (change)="changeValue($event)"
                [checked]="checked"
                type="checkbox"
                class="custom-control-input"
                [id]="inputId"  // <<=== add
            >
            <label class="custom-control-label" [for]="inputId"></label>  // <<=== add
        </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./toggle.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ToggleComponent extends BaseDetachedComponent implements OnInit {
    public checked: boolean = false;
    public switchType = ESwitchType;

    private id: string = '';  // <<=== add = Element ID must be unique on the page

    @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    @Input() type: ESwitchType;
    @Input() size: TValidSize = 'md';
    @Input() isDisabled = false;

    @Input() set value(value: boolean) {
        this.checked = value;
        this.detectChanges();
    }

    get sizeClass(): string {
        let classSize = '';
        switch (this.type) {
            case ESwitchType.switch:
                classSize = 'custom-switch-';
                break;
            case ESwitchType.checkbox:
                classSize = 'checkbox-';
                break;
            case ESwitchType.radio:
                classSize = 'custom-radio-';
                break;
        }

        return classSize + this.size;
    }


   /**
    * Universally Unique Identifier
    */
    get inputId(): string {  // <<=== add
        return this.id;
    }

    constructor(
        protected cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ) {
        super(cdr);

        this.id = uuidv4(); // <<=== add

        cdr.detach();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.detectChanges();
    }

    changeValue(event: Event): void {
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.valueChange.emit((event.target as HTMLInputElement).checked);

        this.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

as an example :

1. [material-checkbox](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/checkbox/checkbox.ts#L78)
2. [material-radio](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/radio/radio.ts#L109)